# Ошибка создания бина при использовании @Autowired пользовательского DAO

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, repository

В проекте со структурой
[image: Структура проекта.]

**TeamsController**

```
@RestController
public class TeamsController {

    @Autowired
    private TeamsService teamsService;
...
}
```

**Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test.api","com.test.service"})
    public class Application {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
            SpringApplication.run(new Class<?>[] {Application.class, JpaConfig.class}, args);
        }
    }
```

**JpaConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.test.service.repository")
public class JpaConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

    ...

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean configureEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(configureDataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.test.model");
...}
...
}
```

**TeamsRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface TeamsRepository extends JpaRepository<TeamsEntity, Long> {
}
```

**TeamsService**

```
public interface TeamsService {
    Collection<TeamsEntity> findAll();

    TeamsEntity findOne(Long id);

    TeamsEntity create(TeamsEntity teamsEntity);

    TeamsEntity update(TeamsEntity teamsEntity);

    void delete(Long id);
}
```

**TeamsServiceImpl**

```
@Service
@Transactional(
        propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS,
        readOnly = true)
public class TeamsServiceImpl implements TeamsService {

    TeamsServiceImpl(){

    }

   @Autowired
    private TeamsRepository teamsRepository;
...
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teamsController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.test.service.TeamsService com.test.api.TeamsController.teamsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teamsServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.test.service.repository.TeamsRepository com.test.service.TeamsServiceImpl.teamsRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teamsRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1b7a52dd' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1b7a52dd': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, проблема была ни в способах инжекта `Repository` в пользовательский `DAO` и ни в том что при конфигурации этого добра были указаны не те пакеты, а в наименовании самой фабрики - поскольку Spring Data JPA ищет `EntityManagerFactory` с именем экземпляра `entityManagerFactory`; это видно в [документации](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html).

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined

Соответственно необходимо либо заменить название метода либо указать спрингу своё название, как было предложено [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520602/spring-data-jpa-no-bean-named-entitymanagerfactory-is-defined-injection-of-a).
P.S.: В следущий раз лог буду читать с конца `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Или можно в сети поискать. Этот [линк](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19699837/1051509) - первый в выдаче гугла.

Comment: хорошо когда знаешь, что искать.